# How to use only 2 broker connections across 15+ number of processes?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

The scenario is - I am building a message queue model using RabbitMQ and phpamqplib. This model will have 15 programs each program will consume a message from a queue and publish a message to another queue. All these queues are different (i.e. around 30 queues). But I want to use only 2 connections across all these programs one for publishing and another one for consuming. I don't want to create broker connections in each of the program. I am not able to understand how to do it? Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each producer or consumer will need a connection to a broker in order to communicate. I'm not sure why you'd think that could be avoided, or why you'd even want to avoid that in the first place.

Comment: I have read in some sites that it is better to have only few connections to the server.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-discuss/-xO1tQafmM4
I have 15 programs. each one will act as producer and consumer. so can I use 15 connections to RabbitMQ server? suggest me any other better way to do it.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't even exist for you. 15 connections is not a problem, and won't be. If your testing and deployment experience shows that it's fine, why bother building an extravagant solution for no reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 2 connections then 15 producers and consumers should be part of a single process and run as threads. In addition two threads one for consuming and other for publishing.

The consumer thread consumes messages and pushes them to remaining worker thread pool.

Once the worker threads have completed their work, response is pushed to an internal storage inside publisher,which in turn pops the response onto rabbit queues.

. Few points to keep in mind are:

1. Throughput: Number of consumers and producers is decided on basis of throughput you want to achieve for your application.
2. Scalability, if you have fixed number of consumers and producers then you might be able to scale your application to a limit.
3. Flow control: number of consumers can be crucial in avoiding connection based flow control.
4. Internal message caching by consumer thread (Qos). Set a well defined QOs value as per the throughout desired.

Also explore if multi-threading is supported by amqp library you desire to use. If yes then you could share the connection across threads.